# RISC-V: Why does the mstatus include SIE, SPIE and SPP?

Tags: riscv

Does `mstatus` really use the `SIE/SPIE/SPP` bits? Or they are just reserved to ensure that `mstatus` is a superset of `sstatus`?

For `mstatus`:

- `MIE` controls whether interrupt processing is enabled in M-mode
- `MPIE` records the `MIE` before entering trap, so that the interrupt enable status before trap can be restored when `mret` is executed later
- `MPP` records the privilege level before the trap, so that the previous privilege level before trap can be restored when `mret` is executed later

So what does `mstatus.SIE/SPIE/SPP` actually do?

Answer (score 1):

From [brucehoult's reddit reply](https://www.reddit.com/r/RISCV/comments/14s26or/comment/jqv4nd5/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

They do exactly the same thing when a trap is delegated to S mode for handling.

There is only one physical `status` register, but different views of it, with M-mode being able to see and change anything and S-mode seeing only a subset.

```
[firmware_main] Clear MSTATUS_MIE | MSTATUS_SIE for mstatus
[firmware_main] mstatus is 0x0
[firmware_main] sstatus is 0x0
[firmware_main] Set MSTATUS_SIE for mstatus
[firmware_main] mstatus is 0x2
[firmware_main] sstatus is 0x2
[firmware_main] Clear MSTATUS_MIE | MSTATUS_SIE for mstatus
[firmware_main] mstatus is 0x0
[firmware_main] sstatus is 0x0
[firmware_main] Set SSTATUS_SIE for sstatus
[firmware_main] mstatus is 0x2
[firmware_main] sstatus is 0x2
```

And refer to: Volume II: RISC-V Privileged Architectures V20211203 P64

> The sstatus register is a subset of the mstatus register.
>
> In a straightforward implementation, reading or writing any field in sstatus is equivalent to reading or writing the homonymous field in mstatus.